# Unable to Edit Chart Data in Powerpoint 2010 64 bit

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel-2010, charts, microsoft-powerpoint

when I create a powerpoint presentation and add a chart, I can edit the data in the excel window that opens initially. However once I close that excel window, I am unable to bring it back up if i want to edit the data. Clicking on Edit Data turns mouse cursor into an hourglass for a few seconds, but then nothing happens. If I check via task manager, then the process excel is started on clicking edit data, but the excel window doesn't open. Even if I close the excel process via task manager and click edit data again, then also the excel sheet with the chart data doesn't open up. Have already reinstalled MS Office, but the problem persists. Latest updates installed for both Windows and Office. I,m sorry if this has been discussed before, I tried searching, but couldn't find any similar Q here, that's why I am posting.

Comment: Please open an Excel spreadsheet first, then try to click Edit Data again in PowerPoint to check this issue. Besides, go to _C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14_, right click **EXCEL.EXE**  > Properties > Compatibility, clear the check box of  Compatibility Mode.

Comment: The suggestion to have Excel open while clicking on Edit Data Works. The compatibility settings were off already. Thanks a lot. Saves me a lot of hassle of starting a new daily graph all from scratch!!

Comment: @EmilyHua If you've time, please copy/paste your comment into the Your Answer field below so Man Mohan can mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Steve Rindsberg, thank you for your kind reminder.

As a workaround, please open an Excel spreadsheet first, then try to click Edit Data again in PowerPoint to check this issue.

Besides, go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14, right click EXCEL.EXE > Properties > Compatibility, clear the check box of Compatibility Mode.